# Is it possible to get the current healthkit status of an iOS user?

Tags: ios, core-motion, healthkit

For instance if I wanted to respond to when a user was walking/running/sedentary/bicycle/etc is that possible in current SDKs?

Answer (score 2):

Lucked upon the answer. In [CMMotionActivityManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CMMotionActivityManager/isActivityAvailable):

The CMMotionActivityManager class provides access to the motion data stored by a device. Motion data reflects whether the user is walking, running, in a vehicle, or stationary for periods of time. A navigation app might look for changes in the current type of motion and offer different directions for each.